# Can installing programs on the same hard drive but different partition overwrite data on the other partition?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, software-rec, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery

The case is I want to recover my data on a hard drive partition, drive E which has gone raw. I want to install a recovery software on drive C which is actually a part of the same hard drive. I have only one hard drive(C drive) present in my computer with its partitions C drive itself and E drive. Installing or using something on C drive shouldn't overwrite data on E drive, am I right?

Comment: You are correct, up to a point. If what you install or use is partitioning software, or something you have previously configured with specific reference to `E:`, then that partition could be accessed and possibly overwritten. The configuration problem can be avoided by removing the `E:` label under disc management, but obviously there is nothing to prevent the use of partitioning software.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think I follow you.

Comment: Maybe I didn't follow your question. When you said drive `E:` has gone raw, I assumed you meant that it is corrupt in some way, but that drive `C;` is intact, allowing you to install software there. Please explain what you don't understand in my comment.

Comment: Yes you are right. How come the partitioning software into picture?

Comment: You were considering using recovery software, which modifies partitions, yet you wanted confirmation that `E:` wouldn't be written to. Maybe it's not the best term, but I was using "partitioning software" as a general description of anything which creates, deletes or modifies partitions. And you did say "installing or using something on drive C", which covers any installable or installed software, including Disc Management, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you Install software or Format even one partition, the rest of the partitions stay untouched. So if you Install software or format C, the E will be untouched.

If the drive is not overwritten then the data  recovery is also possible. It is somewhat tricky, but is possible.

*Remember always, if you repartition and Format the disk then afterwards the data is untraceable, which remains on the disk.*